# what is the answer about this function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function such that $f(f(x))=-x, \forall x \in \mathbb R $. Then which one is correct?

$(a) f$ is an injective map.

$(b)f$ is strictly increasing.

$(c) f$ is strictly decreasing.

$(d)f$ is continuous.

From where to start here I am confused.

Comment: @Rubertos Partition $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ into two sets $A\cup(-A),B\cup(-B)$ with the same cardinality and that are symmetric with respect to the origin. Let $g$ be a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Then define $f(x)=-g(x)$ for $x\in A$, $f(-x)=g(x)$ for $x\in A$, $f(-y)=-g^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in B$, and $f(y)=g^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in B$. Define $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) If $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y$ then $−x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=−y$, which implies $x=y$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $f$ must be injective.

(b) If $f$ is increasing then $f(f(x))$ must be increasing because composing increasing functions gives an increasing function. But $−x$ is not increasing.

(c) If $f$ were strictly decreasing then $f(f(x))$ would be strictly increasing, which again can't be.

(d) A continuous and injective function f:R→R must be monotonic. But we have already shown that this function can't be monotonic.

**Are there such functions $f$?**

There are. Partition $(0,+\infty)=A\cup B$ into two sets $A,B$ with the same cardinality. Let $g:A\to B$ be a bijection.

Define

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x=0\\g(x)&x\in A\\-g^{-1}(x),&x\in B\\-g(-x),&x\in -A\\g^{-1}(-x),&x\in-B\end{cases}$$

Comment: For part (a) you can simply say that $f$ has an inverse, namely $-f$, and is therefore injective.

Comment: @JackM No, that is just hiding the proof that it is injective inside the proof that a function with inverse is injective. There is no gain in simplicity and there is loss in clarity. I would avoid that.